# Best inline lamp switch for intended use

Tags: multiway-switch

I am planning to DIY a lamp for my wife for our bedroom.  Current idea is to have two different lighting features contained in the same lamp.  Idea being your standard lamp(**A**), and am going to be doing an epoxy center section with lighting(**B**).  I would like to be able to control, from a single inline switch if possible, as follows;

**A** - On

OR

**B** - On

OR

**A**+**B** - On

I am pretty certain that I am overthinking this, but I am uncertain where to begin in my search for such an inline swtich.

Any guidance is most certainly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: I suspect nowhere, as an inline cord switch - those have pretty limited functions since there's typically just the two conductors of the lamp cord to work with. The ones that offer different brightness are typically acting as a crude dimmer, not switching different wires.

Comment: I've seen some that used a diode to switch between half and full power.  two of those could control two features with opposite polarities.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the same basic functionality as a **3-way light bulb.** But finding that can be a bit tricky:

- Many of these are designed with the switch and bulb holder/socket as one unit. That won't work for you.
- Searching for "3-way switch" will often find wall switches designed to turn a light on/off from two separate locations.

But here is one [example product of this type from Amazon](https://amzn.to/3NaIpUl):

[image: 3-way switch for lamp]

it is designed for either replacement in an existing lamp or building your own lamp, and it includes wires instead of being built in to a bulb socket. Exactly what you need.

However, safety is a real issue when working with 120V AC. Since most lighting is now LED, I highly recommend working entirely in low voltage (e.g., 12V - 24V). You use a UL or ETL listed adapter (power pack) that plugs into a 120V receptacle and provides you low, **much safer**, power to work with. Then build your lamp using LEDs designed for that voltage. With incandescent bulbs, a typical 3-way bulb was 50W/100W/150W. 150W incandescent is a lot of light. The equivalent LED might be 7W/13W/20W, which can work just fine from a low-voltage, low-current power supply.

Comment: +1 to using low voltage, especially when your parts may or may not be UL certified.

Answer (score -1):

I searched "double inline switch" and found this:

[image]
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005196631558.html

Comment: Hey, it's from aliexpress, what could possibly be wrong with that for an electrical item? Perhaps it's got a CE marking, that means it's Totally Legit, *right?*

Comment: you can probably find the same thing on Amazon at three times the price, but that's not going to change it's quality at all.  yuu'll  problaby find something similar at a lighting specialist store.  being subject to enforcement they will have a quality product.

Comment: Not if it's a direct import on Amazon, and thus not subjected to NRTL testing, no, it won't - both are a terrible place to buy line voltage electrical stuff.